# NodeJS server working locally but not on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, git, web, openshift

I have created a HTTP server on my local machine which serves up a XSS document to be interpreted by another application, and it works fine on my computer. When I push the application to my OpenShift server, however, it doesn't seem to work, as the server doesn't respond to requests on port 80. I had an error originally because I omitted authentication details using .gitignore, but I have solved that now. I just don't have any idea what could be the problem, and I can't debug it from the command line either because it is ran automatically. There may be a way for me to connect to the server through SSH and manually run it, but I'm not sure. Anyone got any idea?

EDIT: Ran it manually and got this:

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1020:19)
    at listen (net.js:1061:10)
    at net.js:1143:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Looks like a problem with listening on a port, should I set it up to print the error in the callback?

Comment: Why is this tagged git?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the error was cause by me not using the local Environment Variables for OpenShift!